# how to set document line spacing in pt format

Tags: fonts

I need a document line spacing 14pt.

I have tried using `baselinestretch` but, does not seem to be working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please, be so kind and show to as in small complete document starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending by `\end{document}` how you try to use `\baselinestretch`.

Comment: Normally the user-level macro is `\linespread` instead of the lower level `\baselinestretch`. If you need exact 14pt leading, you can use `\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont`, where the first argument is the font size and the second the leading. Note that, `\selectfont` is required after low level font selection macros, including `\linespread`, to make them in effect

Comment: What's the main font size of the document? 10, 11 or 12 pt?

Answer (score 3):

This does the trick (at least for ordinary text), using the second parameter for `\fontsize`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

 \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

*Added:*

As @David Carlisle suggests in his comment, it seems more judicious to replace `\AtBeginDocument{....}` with

```
\AtEndPreamble{%
\apptocmd{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont}{}{}
}%
```

Comment: it would be better (just) to define `\normalsize` as if you do it this way any `\normalsize` will reset it, and that can happen pretty much anywhere.

Comment: I confess I didn't think of such implications. I've added another code, always based on `etoolbox`, rather than redefining the whole of `\normalsize`. Hope there's no side effects.

Answer (score 2):

If the main size is 10pt, the default baseline skip is 12pt, so you want it to increase by 1.66667:

```
\documentclass{article}

\linespread{1.16667}

\begin{document}

\the\baselineskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the main size is 11pt, with 13.6pt baselineskip, the factor should be 1.02941:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\linespread{1.02941}

\begin{document}

\the\baselineskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

The small differences from 14pt should be of no concern.

An “automatic version”:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \linespread{ \fp_eval:n { 14pt/\baselineskip } }
  \selectfont
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\the\baselineskip

\texttt{\meaning\baselinestretch}

\end{document}
```

This will set `\baselinestretch` to whatever is needed to accomplish a baseline skip of 14pt without any previous knowledge of how it is set by the class.

[image]