# Line spacing 18 pt in r markdown

Tags: line-spacing, r, markdown

Iam writing my thesis in r markdown and want to change the line spacing to 18 pt. But i cant find a solution for it. I only found the setting for onehalf spacing or 1.5 spacing but no for exactly some arbitrary pt.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! -  Does [how to set document line spacing in pt format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348678/124842) help? Sorry  i'm not familar with markdown.

Comment: I don’t think this is a duplicate of [Change line spacing inside the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83855/164314), since the OP wants explicit leading in `pt` rather than a stretching factor.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate as the question was about RMarkdown, not about latex. Then again, it's maybe not the right place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small package for specifying explicit leading in any unit you want: The [`leading`](https://ctan.org/pkg/leading) package. You use it by including `\usepackage{leading}` in your preamble and then issuing `\leading{18pt}` before the body text. This package essentially does the thing that [@egreg did in this answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348687/164314) (not in LaTeX3 syntax though).

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{leading}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\leading{18pt}
\textbf{10.95\,pt text on 18\,pt leading}: \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: 18 pt leading]